# Maximum entropy probability distribution for $S_T$ implied from discrete market quotes

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus, entropy-pooling

Consider a maturity $T$, for this maturity I have some implied volatility  from market denoted $\sigma^{0}_{i}$. I want to interpolate these volatility using Entropy approach, by using $\sigma^{0}_{i}$ as prior.

From $\sigma^0_i$, market prices of options $C_i$ can be obtained, out of which a probability distribution function $\mathbb{P}_0$ for $S_T$ is derived.

I want to find a distribution $\mathbb{P}$ for $S_T$ such that

- The entropy is maximized
- $\mathbb{P}_0$ is used as prior distribution
- The distribution  $\mathbb{P}$ yields prices as near from market prices as possible.

I know the probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$ is given by the ollowing minimization problem:

$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[\ln\left(\frac{d\mathbb{P}}{d\mathbb{P}^0}\right)-1\right]+\sum_{i}\omega_i\left(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[f_i(S)\right]-C_i\right)^2$

$\mathbb{P}_0$ is the market implied probability distribution of $S_T$ linked to the $\sigma^{0}_{i}$.

$f_i(S)=max(S_T-K,0)$, i.e. the payoff of market call options, with strike $K$

$C_i$ are market prices of call options

$\omega_i$ are weights

Then I understand that the term $\sum_{i}\omega_i\left(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[f_i(S)\right]-C_i\right)^2$ imposes a penalty to deviations to market prices.

But I do not understand the term

$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[\ln\left(\frac{d\mathbb{P}}{d\mathbb{P}^0}\right)-1\right]$

What is the rationale of this term? Why does it maximize entropy?

Comment: What you have there is called the Kullback-Leibler divergence, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence

Comment: @BS. Thank you! Makes much sense :) Do you know where the -1 in the expectation comes from?